# Can I use ADO variables to create a new variable in the same pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I currently have an ADO variable group with 2 variables: sqlDBAutoPauseLocation = eastus2 and sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName = Sandbox. When declaring variables I use:

```
variables:
- group: OOI-DR
```

This allows me to use `$(sqlDBAutoPauseLocation)` throughout the pipeline.

I've been trying to create a new variable with a condition depending on what the sqlDBAutoPauseLocation value is. For example:

```
variables:
  - group: OOI-DR
  - name: targetEnv
    ${{if eq(variables['sqlDBAutoPauseLocation'], 'eastus2')}}:
      value: 'OOI-$(sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName)'
```

And if the starting value was a different location, I would have:

```
variables:
 - group: OOI-DR
 - name: targetEnv
   ${{if eq(variables['sqlDBAutoPauseLocation'], 'eastus2')}}:
     value: 'OOI-$(sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName)'
   ${{if eq(variables['sqlDBAutoPauseLocation'], 'centralus')}}:
     value: 'OOI-$(sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName)-DR'
```

However, I am trying to output the value in my script to ensure that it works like:

```
jobs:
  - deployment: TestName
    environment: 'OOI-$(sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName)'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: AzurePowerShell@5
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '$(ADO_Connection)'
                azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
                ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
                Inline: |
                  Write-Host ${{variables.targetEnv}}
```

This script results in an empty string, so I know one of my previous variables uses is implementing the wrong syntax. Is this actually a possibility with the right runtime syntax?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use ADO variables to create a new variable in the same pipeline?

I could reproduce this issue on my side.

That because the syntax `${{if eq(variables['sqlDBAutoPauseLocation'], 'eastus2')}}` is compile-time variable, but the variable `sqlDBAutoPauseLocation` is a runtime variable.

So, it the condition variable will not work as usually.

To resolve this issue, you could use following syntax:

```
variables:
  - group: 'OOI-DR'

jobs:
- deployment: TestName
  environment: 'OOI-$(sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName)'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - task: InlinePowershell@1
          displayName: 'SetVariableV1'
          inputs:
            Script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetEnv]OOI-$(sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName)"'
          condition: eq(variables['sqlDBAutoPauseLocation'], 'eastus2') 
        
        - task: InlinePowershell@1
          displayName: 'SetVariableV2'
          inputs:
            Script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetEnv]OOI-$(sqlDBAutoPauseEnvName)-DR"'
          condition: eq(variables['sqlDBAutoPauseLocation'], 'centralus') 

        - task: AzurePowerShell@5
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '$(ADO_Connection)'
            azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
            ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
            Inline: |
              Write-Host $(targetEnv)
```